# external javascript not working on subdomain

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, subdomain, external

I'm working on a dev site using isotope on a subdomain and ran into an issue where the javascript isn't working (previews fine in Dreamweaver Live mode), so I created two simple test pages to see what the issue is.

Internal jQuery working:
http://stanley.4pixels.co.uk/index2.html

External jQuery not working
http://stanley.4pixels.co.uk/index3.html

I thought it might be a path issue on the subdomain, but the CSS file works fine on both. I can't honestly see where the problem lies and I'm not new to building websites... only this server (WHM cPanel), so maybe it's something there?

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console? network tab? Frankly, I'm not going to visit random sites on the internet to check your work. Include the relevant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.js is just one line of comment... it does nothing.

It looks like this:

```
// JavaScript Document$(document).ready(function(){ "use strict";  $("button").click(function(){    $(".box").slideToggle();  });});
```

No new line between comment and real code.

Comment: Not in my js file, so it must be stripping out returns somewhere. I'll delete the comment

Comment: Thanks guys, the comment which was on it's own line was losing any return  when uploaded so cancelling out the js

Answer (score 0):

I think you have removed newline in the hope of removing white spaces.

Just add proper formatting or white spaces to make your code work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("button").click(function() {
       $(".box").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Download this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jKwkZY3dIQHgEpx2dTEO) for working code.